# Can virus (spy) apps install custom firmware (custom ROM) in a rooted Android phone?

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, malware

I heard spy apps can root Android phones. If the phone is rooted and spy apps are installed, can spy apps install a custom ROM in that Android phone?

Comment: Theoretically if your phone has a vulnerability and an app uses that vulnerability to gain root it could install a custom ROM. But custom ROMs have to be device specific and you first would have to unlock the bootloader which causes all user data to be erased. That should attract the attention of even the stupidest user and thus is a bad idea for a malware which wants to stay undetected...

Comment: Malware with enough privileges (manually granted or gained through a vulnerability) can do anything which includes burning your device. But installing custom ROM doesn't make much sense from a hacker's perspective. They are very goal-oriented and rarely do purposeless things.

Comment: I thought spy apps and can have remote controll so, isnt it possible that they unlock the bootloader by themsleves ?